# How to left-align with snprintf

Tags: c, printf

I am writing some C code and have been formatting strings like this

```
int buffer[8];
snprintf(buff, 8, "%3d", someNumberVariable);
my_lcd_stringout(buffer);
```

This formats any texts that grows in size to be pushed to the left. For example, imagine the _ character is a space:

```
"__7__"
"_74__"
"748__"
```

Does anybody know how I can reverse this pushback? so that my increasing numbers are formatted this way as they grow (without leaving the characters there when they shrink of course):

```
"__7__"
"__74_"
"__748"
```

Comment: Use two leading spaces in the format string, and left-justification instead of the default right?

Comment: Where do the 2 trailing spaces in your results come from? `"748__"` etc. You do not print them in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"  %-3d"`

The minus makes it left-aligned.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Tom Sorry for being brutally frank, but you should have been able to find this in less time than than it took to write your question and wait for this answer to be posted,. Just about any decent tutorial, book or class should have had information about it. And if the book, tutorial or class didn't mention it, and didn't include links to any other resource or reference where something like this could easily be found, then IMO you should look for other sources to learn C.

Comment: @Tom If nothing else, I recommend e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), together with some experimenting.

Comment: @Tom Your comment indicates that this answer solved your problem. If so, please consider to accept the answer.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, They probably could have found it, but it can be hard if you don't know the right term (which is the case here).

Comment: @Tom, Re "*Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)*", The proper way to communicate this is by checking the mark next to the answer.

Comment: Well, the art of developing includes the ability to read and understand, even if it is more than a single page. And this is the first skill I expect from a beginner. +1 for @Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: @the busybee, Which is it, "in less time than than it took to write your question" or "even if it's more than a single page [of incredibly dense text without knowing the right words to look for]"? Those are mutually exclusive. If you're going to claim to agree with someone, make sure not to say exactly the opposite!

Comment: You're right, I don't agree with you. Especially the page Someprogrammerdude linked is crystal clear "_-: the result of the conversion is left-justified within the field (by default it is right-justified)_", found in seconds if searched for "left". -- And a little experiment is done in a handful of minutes. Unbeatable. -- It's not just the OP's time, all the visitors' time to read, understand, and reply adds to it. We rather spend time on _real_ problems. I'm missing this self-teaching skill heavily on today's newbies.

Comment: In contrary: the OP uses "left" in the title and in the prose. -- Someprogrammerdude said "_but you should have been able to find this in less time than than it took to write your question and wait for this answer to be posted_", which is my point, too. -- Case closed, I'm off.

Comment: *plonk* Have a nice day.

Comment: For someone so worried about wasting their time, u guys sure seem to spend a lot of time arguing in this comment section lol

Comment: The irony of their claim didn't escape me, but I wasn't going to pick on them further.